# best way to prevent usage of mobile phones inside workplace

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, phone

In a recent audit by one of our client they advised to block mobile phones inside office campus since the client fears that employees will take snapshots of client data,So we decided to block the usage of cellphones inside campus

what would be the best way to implement it,The problems which we might face were :

- the employees cant attend emergency calls from unknown numbers
- the employees cant attend emergency client calls

we thought of implementing cellphone jammer but many of employees were handling clients through mobile phones,

but in other side if we allow mobile phones inside campus for the employees whom attending client calls will raise discrimination b/w employees

possible solutions we discussed were :

- Providing seperate numbers for clients
- implementing cellphone jammer(optional doesnt consider it,its suggested by one of the employees so we kept as a suggestion)

other than above,what would be the best method to implement it?

Comment: Mobile phones without cameras.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does a cell phone jammer stop the phone's camera? If the concern is actually that employees will take pictures of client data, then you're going to have to search every employee as they come through the door.

Comment: @scaaahu but we cant force every employee to buy a non camera phone since most of the employees were already using smartphones cant switch it at a moment,

Comment: @JoelEtherton cellphone jammers might be one of the solution,since there is no calls and communication the employees gradually think it is no use of bringing in mobiles inside,

Comment: If your problem is mobile phone cameras why do you think connectivity is relevant? Also, frequency jamming is illegal in a lot of jurisdictions anyway.

Comment: This is a request from the client, right? Charge them the expense, i.e. buy the employees the non camera phones.

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 are you protecting against malicious photography?

Comment: @NathanCooper yep friend its one of the major concerns which client fears ,the employee might take photographs and use it personally for malicious purpose

Comment: Refuse the request, trust your employees, and put severe consequences in place for anyone caught photographing sensitive materials. This kind of problem is typically the domain of defense contractors handling "top secret" info-- they're somewhat justified in taking draconian approaches, but unless you're handling life or death issues, it would be ridiculous to ban phones.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Yes. Maybe I'm not familiar with the available technology, but my understanding is that cell phone jammers would stop people from making or receiving cell phone calls. They would do nothing to prevent someone from taking a picture. Your proposed solution creates a whole bunch of problems, while doing absolutely zero to solve the original problem. If the problem was that employees were spending a lot of time on personal calls, a cell phone jammer would be a plausible solution.

Comment: RE "Employees gradually think it is no use bringing mobile phones inside" This would only apply to employees who want to use their mobile phones to make calls. If an employee is planning on using the camera to steal proprietary information, the fact that he can't make calls is irrelevant. So the policy is only effective against employees who have no plans to do the thing that you're really worried about, while having no effect on any who might actually be a problem. Unless, I suppose, your fear is that employees will ACCIDENTALLY photograph sensitive information while taking selfies.

Comment: If you must do this, you could turn your space into a [Faraday Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). However, that alone wouldn't stop someone from taking a picture, storing it on their phone or camera or another device, and then transferring the picture to an undesirable recipient after they have left the premises.

Comment: In the USA, blocking cell phone signals is illegal and you can be fined by the FCC.

Comment: @Andy: The OP's profile states he's in India.

Comment: @GreenMatt Then the location should be added to the question.  And this site is read by people outside of India too, so I don't see why pointing out the legalities of the USA shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Andy: While I get your point about adding the location, there are lots of questions on this site where the location isn't specified, but where it could make a difference - feel free go through and tag them appropriately. If you're going to add info about the USA to this question, then you ought to do so for every country. Also, the FCC bans *jamming*. However, blocking can be achieved by other means, which are outside the FCC's purview.

Comment: @GreenMatt This question has been closed, and frankly i'm not going to go through every question to clean up after posters; location really should be mandatory.  As far as passive blocking, i'm not so sure that's outside the FCC's reach either.  Section 333 of the Communications Act says “No person shall willfully or maliciously interfere with or cause interference to any radio communications of any station licensed or authorized by or under this Act.”  So passive blocking could be willful interference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26129/discussion-between-greenmatt-and-andy).

Comment: Phones are not the risk, people are the risk.  If the wrong people have access to this important information, you've already lost.  Blocking the phones in the campus is a false sense of security

Comment: @Joel Etherton: There are also cameras in devices other than phones, and even (gasp!) stand-alone cameras, some of which can be pretty small: http://www.brickhousesecurity.com/category/hidden+cameras/small+hidden+cameras.do  Anyone seriously interested in spying could get something like that, so all banning/jamming cell phones would do is to tell the majority of honest employees that you don't trust them.

Comment: Unless your client is listx (companies dealing with CNI / security issues)  you might tell them to get over them selves

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would **push back and question the assumptions behind the requirement**.

Assuming employees have access to customer data on their computers, **there are countless other ways to "smuggle" out data**.  For example, they can take screenshots (the ability to do this is built into most all OS's), or copy and paste as text, or export into another format; or just plain old save to disk, etc; then send out via email, or paste into a web form, or copy onto a USB key, or transfer via Bluetooth, etc.  There was a case a while back (can't remember the details) where somebody copied confidential data into drafts of emails, then copied the drafts outside the office and deleted them -- hey presto, data out, no traces whatseoever.
And a nefarious, technically skilled and/or professional adversary will come up with lots more: for starters, have you seen the [kind of places](http://www.gadgetsandgear.com/wearable-cameras-body-worn-spy-video.html) you can hide a camera these days?

So unless you're willing to go full-on Pentagon when it comes to your security measures (body searches on entry and exit, airgapped network, completely locked down workstations, regular sweeps for rogue wifi and other transmitting devices, etc) and bear the costs, telling employees that they can't use/bring in their mobiles is just going to **sap productivity, lower morale, waste time *and* cost money, all without addressing the actual problem**.

Convincing the customer about this will, of course, be the tricky part.  You could tell them that you care about their security, and you're willing to implement the Pentagon-style security if they're willing to pay for it, here's how much it will cost you.  Or you could adopt a fig leaf approach: bundle the people working on super secret customer data into a separate room and make them all swear a super secret pinky promise to leave their phones in the magic basket outside when they enter.

Comment: The OP didn't say who the client is or what data they are protecting, they may be legally obligated to comply in order to keep the contract.

Comment: @kleineg Everything in business is negotiable.  If they have no leverage, use the "fig leaf" approach above and comply with the letter of the requirement.

Comment: A separate room with different security protocols is an excellent idea. For example, a company I worked for had two contracts with very different entities. For the one there was specifications on what sort of lock was on the door, how much sound could escape the walls, the workstations were locked down, there was a guard with a cellphone detector and log in sheet, and all employees had clearance. This was all specified and required for the contract. The employees on the other contract could carry cell phones and standard background check... as long as they stayed where they were supposed to.

Comment: @kleineg OP states "advised"

Comment: A separate room with different security protocols is exactly how the government handles its sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the answers assume this is a management want rather than a requirement.  If this absolutely has to be done, limit the physical area where data can be accessed, install an actual securtiy gaurd who has a locking set of cabinets that the cell phones go in, establish and enforce consequences for breaking security protocol.

Comment: Having worked for DoD in a building that contained highly classified information, yes this is what it takes.  However, if the client is anyone except DoD or a similar agency that handles classified information, I would at least try to push back the requirement by telling them that if they want that level of security, they will have to pay the salary of the security guard and any costs of making building and network changes to ensure the data can only be accessed in the secure space.

Comment: And to be sure the data was not being stolen, they would also have to check all papers removed from the space (you could hand write the data you wanted to steal) and ensure no other types of data recording devices (thumb drives, backup tapes, etc.) are removed from the room except physical, encrypted backup tapes being sent to an offsite location.

Answer (score 1):

Cell phone jammers are illegal in many jurisdictions, and would not stop pictures from being taken. However cell phone detectors are fairly straightforward to buy and use. Post a detector at each entrance and ask people stopped entering with a cellphone to leave it in their cars. Once inside, either issue a cell phone without a camera to each person who needs it, or use land lines. Depending on the client and the data, they may be under legal restrictions on how secure the data must be. For example a government contractor handling classified material must implement safeguards.

Answer (score 1):

But that audit point is just silly.  When you consider the risk profile of protecting data that alone does nothing.  That is just someone coming up with an audit point.

> In a recent audit by one of our client they advised to block mobile
>   phones inside office campus.

There are two problems with that.

- Mobile phone are not the only way to take a snapshot
- If the data is available inside *office campus* that alone is the bigger risk profile

Even silly I bet the client meant block a cell phone physically not just block usage.

A serious security audit would have items like

- Do you have a training program regarding customer data security and
  confidentiality
- Do employees sign a customer data security and confidentiality
  policy
- Do you perform a background check on all emplyees
- Do you limit employee access to customer data to only those on the
  project
- Do you have an audit trail of which employees accessed customer data

It is not reasonable to secure a campus of cell phone nor restrict an employee from a cell phone at their desk.

If the data is that confidential then the data should be restricted to a clean room void of printers and USB devices.  Restricted access and no recording devices.

If data is available on the general campus then restricting cell phones is not going to protect data if someone wants to copy it.

As for the direct question "how to implement it?". 
If *it* is block cell phones on the campus then don't.
Tell the customer that block cell phone on the entire campus is not readily enforceable and puts an undue burden on employees.  Don't add it does not really secure the data.
Propose another reasonable security policy and practice. Or if you have a reasonable security policy and practice in place currently then just report the existing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment replies and the question itself, this sounds very much like a management team attempting to formulate policy on topics for which they have absolutely no understanding either of the technology or of the actual risk being mitigated.

Unless this client has deep, deep pockets and "drives" the business (meaning that if this client were to leave it would be extremely disastrous), the expense to enforce such a restriction is prohibitive. However, if the risk is genuine and affects all clients, then it might just need to be implemented anyway simply to avoid the possibility of harmful litigation or industrial damage (such as the leaking of trade secrets or proprietary information).

Short of putting in metal detectors and security personnel to perform searches of employees both entering and exiting the facilities, the only real deterrent will be monitoring and punishment. People who come in contact with sensitive data will need to be made aware of their responsibilities and the repercussions of disseminating that information through any means (cell phone or not).

If your management puts in a policy of "no phones on campus", then there must be strict punishment guidelines and security personnel should be given the equipment necessary to to monitor work areas. There are several precedents for these kinds of policies. Both Microsoft and Apple have similar policies regarding the taking of pictures on their campuses, and they've been moderately successful at maintaining these policies.